# how to get phonegap and cordova working on windows 7

Tags: cordova

I installed phonegap using node.js and tried to build the sample application under windows commandline and it failed on "platform add android".

I then tried to use cordova and downloaded cordova 3.3.0 using node.js and tried to build the sample "Hello" application from command line and it failed on 'platform add android'.   Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing incorrectly.

I kind of expected that if you followed the directions explicitly for the sample application, it should work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Android SDK? You'll need that when you add the android platform to a project. The same applies to other platforms such as Windows 8. Look at the Cordova guides for the details. [Cordova Platform Guides](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) and [Cordova Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)